How can I make virt-install boot from a keydrive/usbstick image?
virt-install 4.1.0 on nixos 23.11
I am trying to install from a memory stick image with the following options:
      opt=(
        --name pfsense
        --ram=4096
        --vcpus=4
        --os-variant=freebsd11.0
        --disk path="$img"
        --disk path="$disk",size=10,format=qcow2
        --boot hd,bootmenu.enable=on,bios.useserial=on
        --graphics none
        --console target_type=serial
      )

      virt-install "${opt[@]}" "${@:2}"

where $img is pfSense-CE-memstick-serial-2.4.5-RELEASE-amd64.img
when running the command, I get this output:
WARNING  KVM acceleration not available, using 'qemu'
ERROR    
An install method must be specified
(--location URL, --cdrom CD/ISO, --pxe, --import, --boot hd|cdrom|...)

Which seems nonsensical to me, as I have specified --boot hd

have you managed to make boot from USB work?
